# How to set env variable in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, jupyter-notebook

I've a problem that Jupyter can't see env variable in bashrc file. Is there a way to load these variables in jupyter or add custom variables to it?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

To set an env variable in a jupyter notebook, just use a `%` magic commands, either `%env` or `%set_env`, e.g., `%env MY_VAR=MY_VALUE` or `%env MY_VAR MY_VALUE`.  (Use `%env` by itself to print out current environmental variables.)

See: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html

Comment: I deleted my earlier comments as they weren't quite accurate - but note that the %env and %set_env magic commands use `os.environ[var] = val` on the backend: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magics/osm.py#L430

Comment: @michael Is there any way to persist the environment across all notebooks? Setting the environment this way seems to only persist the environment for the current notebook.

Comment: @michael, how does one unset an env var?

Comment: @questionto42 I absolutely did not in any way mean to imply that `set_env` was at all "like" a `!shell` command, on the contrary, I said exactly the opposite, that these settings do not somehow transcend the notebook page itself & do NOT actually set an OS env var (hence will NOT be there for subsequent `!shell` commands), but my comment was in response to a now deleted comment & the context is lost. Like the comment I replied to, I'll delete my comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: For anyone wondering, `%set_env` is not like a !shell command. `%set_env` will fail the same way as `os.environ[]` if code must work with environment variables set in the command prompt unless you tweak the settings. See the answers below: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326270/11154841), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77857149/11154841) with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` proof.

Answer (score 101):

### You can also set the variables in your `kernel.json` file:

My solution is useful if you need the same environment variables every time you start a jupyter kernel, especially if you have multiple sets of environment variables for different tasks.

To create a new ipython kernel with your environment variables, do the following:

- Read the documentation at https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kernels.html#kernel-specs
- Run `jupyter kernelspec list` to see a list with installed kernels and where the files are stored.
- Copy the directory that contains the kernel.json (e.g. named `python2`) to a new directory (e.g. `python2_myENV`).
- Change the `display_name` in the new `kernel.json` file.
- Add a `env` dictionary defining the environment variables.

Your kernel json could look like this (I did not modify anything from the installed kernel.json except `display_name` and `env`):

```
{
 "display_name": "Python 2 with environment",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/usr/bin/python2",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "env": {"LD_LIBRARY_PATH":""}
}
```

### Use cases and advantages of this approach

- In my use-case, I wanted to set the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which effects how compiled modules (e.g. written in C) are loaded. Setting this variable using `%set_env` did not work.
- I can have multiple python kernels with different environments.
- To change the environment, I only have to switch/ restart the kernel, but I do not have to restart the jupyter instance (useful, if I do not want to loose the variables in another notebook). See -however - https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2647

Comment: Can you please advise me how do I add ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe``` to existing system path using your suggested technique? Will it work if I am not using admin account? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Homebrew's Python overwrites `sys.executable` unless `PYTHONEXECUTABLE` is set beforehand, which you have to set before python runs.

Comment: In my opinion this is the *only* correct answer, because it uses only Jupyter itself, rather than depending on the functionality being available in any specific kernel.

Comment: And how do I reach those variable names inside jupyter?

Comment: This works for me, but remember to add the correct value you want for the environment variable. The way it is written (at least for me in Jupyter Lab) just erases the variable alltogether. For example, to be able to run Tensorflow on a Jupyter Notebook, I used: `"env": {"LD_LIBRARY_PATH":"/opt/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"}`.

Comment: I had some problems making VS Code to use the updated `kernel.json` file. What finally worked for me was to create an `.env` file in the Workspace root and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` there.

Comment: Thanks! This is the best way to let ctypes.CDLL respect LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: When using vs code jupyter and python env, make `.env` file in your workspace and write `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` into it. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variables

Answer (score 81):

If you're using Python, you can define your environment variables in a `.env` file and load them from within a Jupyter notebook using [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv).

Install python-dotenv:

```sh
pip install python-dotenv
```

Load the `.env` file in a Jupyter notebook:

```py
%load_ext dotenv
%dotenv
```

Answer (score 26):

You can setup environment variables in your code as follows:

```
import sys,os,os.path
sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('~/code/eol_hsrl_python'))
os.environ['HSRL_INSTRUMENT']='gvhsrl'
os.environ['HSRL_CONFIG']=os.path.expanduser('~/hsrl_config')
```

This if of course a temporary fix, to get a permanent one, you probably need to export the variables into your `~.profile`, more information can be found [here](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469160-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-)

Comment: Thanks Kardaj, exporting the variable in ~/.profile solved it, seems that it's not reading from bashrc which is kinda weird.

Comment: michael's answer with `%env MY_VAR=MY_VALUE` should be the correct answer to this question

Comment: @SidaZhou why is michael's answer better?

Comment: @SidaZhou depends on use case - if you want creds to be available in env - and don't want creds to be in your notebook (e.g. on source control) then this isn't ideal.

Comment: Using `%set_env` or `os.environ[]` will fail if code needs to run with settings from the command prompt, when you just cannot set the variables in Python, for example with CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES, see these answers below: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326270/11154841), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77857149/11154841).

Answer (score 20):

A gotcha I ran into: The following two commands are equivalent. Note the first **cannot** use quotes. Somewhat counterintuitively, quoting the string when using `%env VAR ...` will result in the quotes being included as part of the variable's value, which is probably not what you want.

```
%env MYPATH=C:/Folder Name/file.txt
```

and

```
import os
os.environ['MYPATH'] = "C:/Folder Name/file.txt"
```

Comment: Could it be it doesn't affect Jupyter on VS Code on Windows?

Comment: @Royi Not just on Windows, but in a Jupyter Notebook on Linux, this did not change the environment variable either, at least not well enough: it does change something as it does somehow claim the memory, but it does not seem to fully pass it to the compiler, it seems to be a rights issue of the user that you are in. **`%set_env` and `os.environ[]` will both fail if code must run with settings from the command prompt and not in Python.** See the answers below: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326270/11154841), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77857149/11154841) with CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES proof.

Answer (score 9):

If you need the variable set before you're starting the notebook, the only solution which worked for me was `env VARIABLE=$VARIABLE jupyter notebook` with `export VARIABLE=value` in `.bashrc`.

In my case tensorflow needs the exported variable for successful importing it in a notebook.

Comment: Or if you do not want to change the .bashrc, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77857149/11154841) with CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES proof.

Answer (score 6):

A related (short-term) solution is to store your environment variables in a single file, with a predictable format, that can be sourced when starting a terminal and/or read into the notebook. For example, I have a file, `.env`, that has my environment variable definitions in the format `VARIABLE_NAME=VARIABLE_VALUE` (no blank lines or extra spaces). You can source this file in the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files when beginning a new terminal session and you can read this into a notebook with something like,

```
import os
env_vars = !cat ../script/.env
for var in env_vars:
    key, value = var.split('=')
    os.environ[key] = value
```

I used a relative path to show that this `.env` file can live anywhere and be referenced relative to the directory containing the notebook file. This also has the advantage of not displaying the variable values within your code anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using systemd I just found out that you seem to have to add them to the systemd unit file. This on Ubuntu 16. Putting them into the .profile and .bashrc (even the /etc/profile) resulted in the ENV Vars not being available in the juypter notebooks.

I had to edit:

```
/lib/systemd/system/jupyer-notebook.service
```

and put in the variable i wanted to read in the unit file like:

```
Environment=MYOWN_VAR=theVar
```

and only then could I read it from within juypter notebook.

Answer (score 3):

If your notebook is being spawned by a Jupyter Hub, you might need to configure (in `jupyterhub_config.py`) the list of environment variables that are allowed to be carried over from the JupyterHub process environment to the Notebook environment by setting

```
c.Spawner.env_keep = [VAR1, VAR2, ...]
```

(https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/spawner.html#jupyterhub.spawner.Spawner.env_keep)

See also: [`Spawner.environment`](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/spawner.html#jupyterhub.spawner.Spawner.environment)

Answer (score 3):

you can run jupyter notebook with docker and don(t have to manage dependancy leaks.

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /home/mee/myfolder:/home/jovyan --name notebook1 jupyter/notebook
docker exec -it notebook1 /bin/bash
```

then kindly ask jupyter about the opened notebooks,
`jupyter notebook list`
*http://* *0.0.0.0:8888/?token=012456788997977a6eb11e45fffff*
Url can be copypasted, verify port if you have changed it.

Create a notebook and paste the following,
into the notebook

```py
!pip install python-dotenv
import dotenv
%load_ext dotenv
%dotenv
```

Comment: Second part perfectly worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

##### TLDR

In a Jupyter Notebook on Linux, when loading a PyTorch model, I had to run `!export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1` to spread the tensors on two GPUs. It was the only way to get the ParallelData code to work. `os.environ[]` or `%set_env` do not work.

##### This answer is almost a duplicate of another answer here

This seems to be the same if you work with Keras, see [this answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326270/11154841), which this answer takes up, but this answer goes a bit further:

- It shall show you more ways to run the code without having to change the .bashrc or the Jupyter Notebook service settings.
- And it stresses that most of the other answers can be plain wrong, at least if you have to split the tensors among GPUs, and there might be other settings where Python code cannot steer the environment variables well enough.

##### Shell commands: `export` / `MY_ENV_VAR=0,1 python some_cuda_executable.py`

For `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` and maybe other variables, `%set_env` or `os.environ[]` do not work, this Stack Overflow [How to make Jupyter Notebook run on one specified gpu of multi-gpus?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73139900/11154841) ran into the same thing. **Thus, in some settings, you just have to run a command in the CLI and not in Python**, and then, there is no way to do this in pure Python code.

Instead:

- `!export ...` (in a Jupyter Notebook cell *together* with the code that needs these environment variables; it must be the same cell and must be run at the beginning of it).
- You can also run it in a CLI execution like with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4,5,6,7 python forward_test_ins.py`.

The main thing is that you should not write `os.environ[]` or `%set_env` in the code unless you tweak the .bashrc (untested), see [this answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326270/11154841), or the Jupyter Notebook service settings (untested), see [this answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43217327/11154841)
But mind: the error will also be thrown outside of a Jupyter Notebook, if you run a python file.
Also check [this answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53595397/11154841) for the kernel.json file (untested).

##### Further links

For more, see:

- [How to Solve "CUDA: Invalid Device Ordinal" Error in PyTorch Single-GPU Inference on a Model Trained with DataParallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77856985/11154841) that proves that it does not work for both `os.environ[]` and `%set_env` with code,
- this CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES example for parallel computing with many GPUs at [Transformers Trainer: "RuntimeError: module must have its parameters ... on device cuda:6 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:0"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126493/97556),
- the entries at [setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES just has no effect #9158](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9158#issuecomment-665513010).

Answer (score -1):

if you have vsCode just create the env like always in the terminal then go to the jupyter file then click select kernel in the top right side then the command palette will open with the env path just click on it and it will take the env.

Comment: The question is not about a virtual environment but about an environment variable.