# SageMath kernel death in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: kernel, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, sage

I followed the instructions in
[How to install SageMath kernel in Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39296020)
but as soon as a I create a new SageMath worksheet
in the Jupyter Notebook, the worksheet opens, and,
after a few seconds, I get a message saying the
Sage kernel died. This, without having the time
to ask for the least computation.

I don't experiment this issue with the Python 3 kernel.
I am running all this on Ubuntu 18.04.

Could it be related to my installation of Jupyter,
which is based on Python 3, while, if I understand well,
Sage runs using Python 2.

I installed Jupyter following the `pip install` instructions
of [jupyter.org](https://jupyter.org):

```sh
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
$ python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

Comment: Can you give us a link as to where you saw how to install SageMath in Jupyter?  It is possible that the version conflict would matter, though Sage runs its own Python.

Comment: @kcrisman -- link is now fixed.