# setting environment variables from google colab to local machine

Tags: environment-variables, google-colaboratory

I'm training a model on google colab, and im running this model on my local machine.

unfortunately, the environment variables on my local machine are very different from google colab's. I tried using conda on colab, but it's very difficult to use there.

is there an effective way to export environment variables from google colab and run them on local machine.

or the other way around to.

Thank you

Comment: What did you try specifically, and what error did you encounter?

Comment: Did you used <i pip install> for installation?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named `.env` with this format:

```
KEY1=VALUE1
KEY2=VALUE2
```

Then upload the file and set the varialbles:

```
# upload .env file
from google.colab import files
files.upload()

env_list = ! cat .env
for v in env_list: 
    %set_env $v
```

You can also use [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) initially mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028874/10473854) question.

The approach mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909045/10473854) question is probably the best to way to handle this setting environment variables in general, however, at least I couldn't find a simple way to use the result of a shell command in a magic command.