# How to change Jupyter Notebook (Windows) shell to bash

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently running Jupyter Notebook (Windows 7) within a Conda environment using Python 3.6.4 and my current version of Jupyter Notebook is 5.6.0. I came across the following article: [Using Git Bash in Jupyter Notebook on Windows](https://medium.com/@konpat/using-git-bash-in-jupyter-noteobok-on-windows-c88d2c3c7b07) , that explains how to change the default shell within Jupyter Notebook to Bash by changing the config "C.NotebookApp.terminado_settings = {'shell_command': ['C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe']}. I've tried multiple different options for the path to bash, including just the name 'bash', with no success.

[image: Python and Jupyter version]
Python and Jupyter version:

[image: Juypter Notebook shell not changed]
Jupyter Notebook: Not changed, still using Powershell

I've read up on the [Jupyter Notebook: Read the Docs](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) , and made the changes to the jupyter_notebook_config.py found under C:\Users\UserName\.jupyter directory, without any success.

[image: jupter_notebook_config.py terminado configuration]

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution to your problem is to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).
I am under Windows 10, conda 4.5.11 and Jupyter lab 0.35.3. I have also activated the Windows subsystem for Linux (WSL). 
Using `!wsl` you can call the WSL or with `%%bash` for cell magics.
Inside Jupyter Lab I have:
[image]

is the %%bash cell magic referring to the WSL? According to my tests yes, I can access the same programs and I am taken to the WSL when I run bash.exe from the Conda prompt. There is an integration of the PowerShell prompt to WSL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop). The same seems to work with the conda prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three options:

1. If one opens Jupyter notebook via GitBash with `jupyter notebook` then `%%bash` magics should work
2. If one wishes to always be able to run bash within a Jupyter Notebook opened via Anaconda Prompt (similarly using `jupyter notebook`):

   - Edit the Jupyter Notebook config file:

     - Location can be found via Anaconda Prompt with `jupyter --config-dir`
     - Open the jupyter_notebook_config.py file in this directory using notepad or an IDE
     - Modify and save with the line of code: `c.NotebookApp.terminado_settings = {}` pointed instead to your bash executible (e.g.): `c.NotebookApp.terminado_settings = { 'shell_command': ['C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe'] }`
   - Edit your system environment variables:

     - Windows Search (with admin rights) > "Edit the System Environment Variables" > Environment Variables > Highlight "path" > Edit > Add a new line with C:\Program Files\Git\bin > OK out of all windows
3. [Set an environment variable in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890898/how-to-set-env-variable-in-jupyter-notebook)