# How to change Jupyter notebook (windows) shell to bash in Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, git-bash

Related question: [How to change Jupyter Notebook (Windows) shell to bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330492/how-to-change-jupyter-notebook-windows-shell-to-bash)

On windows 10, I created the jupyter configuration file by doing:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

then edited this file to include the path to my git bash executable:

```
c.NotebookApp.terminado_settings = {
   'shell_command': ['C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe']
}
```

as referenced in the relevant question above.

On git bash, I then tried to start a jupyter notebook session and I verified that git bash commands worked, e.g. doing:

```
!ls
```

worked on the notebook client in my browser.

However, if I open an [interactive window](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) or a Jupyter notebook within **Visual studio code**, I do not get the expected behavior, I instead get the error

`'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

My question then is:

How do you get jupyter on Visual studio code to use git bash instead of Command prompt on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
go to settings->search for cmd->change it to location of bash-> probably you need to restart VS code

tested with !ls

[image: setting_location]