# Select shell for interactive window in vscode

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code

## TLDR

**How can I select the shell that is used for the jupyter interactive notebooks, in vscode?**

## Details

I have several shells installed on my machine: the factory-installed `zsh` and `bash` and a newer `bash`.

In vscode, the terminal window (A in screenshot) can be configured to use any one of these. This means that e.g. aliases and exports in that shell (like `BELVIS_USR` in this case) defined are available.

So far, so good. But.

I also run much code in the interactive window (B). There, apparently a different shell is used, as the same environment variable is not available (C).

This question is not about defining environment variables to be used in the interactive window, but rather which shell is being used by it. Filtering the settings by 'interactive', I do not find a settings for the shell like there is in case of the integrated terminal.

**How can I ensure the interactive code is run in my shell of choice?**

[image]

Comment: If you're on a UNIX system, you can check the `SHELL` environment variable to see what shell contributed to the environment variables. As for changing, maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/52330492/11107541 helps?

Comment: Thanks @starball. Strangely, `os.environ['SHELL']` (in the notebook) returns the same filepath as `echo $SHELL` in the terminal (`/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`). Yet, in the former, `os.environ['BELVIS_USR']` gives a keyerror, whereas `echo $BELVIS_USR` in the terminal has the expected value. The export `BELVIS_USR` is defined in `~/.bashrc`. Am I missing a step that makes the export available in the notebook?

Comment: any other suggestions? Anyone?