# How to use API Key without directly using it in the Python code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, access-token

I want get data using HubSpot API in Python, however, I don't want to show my ApiKey in the code. What would be the best practice to get data using API Without showing your API key? I am currently working in Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdgIWTYQ69A u can flow this tutorial

Simply create a file name ".env" and write your API key in
Like this :
"API_KEY = YOUR_API_KEY"

then run "pip3 install python-dotenv" in your cmd

then in your code, add some lines :

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

API_KEY=os.getenv("API_KEY")
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it says 'none'.

Comment: Where do u put your .env file ?

Comment: it's in my C drive

Comment: This worked for me in my ipynb notebook

Comment: worked.   "pip install python-dotenv"

Answer (score 2):

You would be looking to store the API key in your environment variables, then read from the environment variables in your python code.

In Jupyter you could achieve this with magic commands;
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html

Set with

```
%env VAR_KEY VAR_VALUE
```

You can then use these with

```
import os
os.getenv(key)
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6uvG.png)

Alternatively, instead of magic commands you could set the env variable in your kernel.json, see here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/53595397/12707704