# Change environment variable setted in jupyter Notebook with magics

Tags: jupyter-notebook, environment-variables, langchain

Hope this question is not already answered, I've searched many posts but none of them says how to change an environment variable.

I wanted to load environment variables in `.env` so followed the steps in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44251637/10095656).

```py
%env "OPENAI_API_KEY"=OPENAI_API_KEY
```

Then I wanted to see my variable with:

```
%env OPENAI_API_KEY
```

Everything worked well but my mistake was to erroneously copy the value for my environment variable. So I want to change it.

I tried dotenv to load this variable again but seems not to work.

Hope you can help me, please.

I tried doing again the same procedure so that it can be changed/updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you made a mistake writing your APIKEY:

Created a `.env` with your credentials:

```
OPENAI_API_KEY="...erroneous-api-key..."
```

You verified:

```
%env OPENAI_API_KEY
```

And you realized it is wrong.

You can:

```
import os
del os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
```

Then:

```
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]="...right-key..."
```

To verify this:

```
%env OPENAI_API_KEY
```

And the updated api-key should be prompted.